# How can I fade-out the sound played by MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, audio, fadeout, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'd like to fade-out the sound played by `MPMusicPlayerController` over a particular time period?  **How can I do this?**

Comment: Did you look at the volume method?

Comment: i want to fade it as fade continuously not simply slowing down the volume

Answer (score 6):

There is no fade functionality so you have to implement it yourself. Loop until volume is 0, and add a delay for each step. If you want all this to happen 2 seconds into the future, put the code on a block:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *iPod = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

int64_t delay = 2LL * NSEC_PER_SEC;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delay), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    while (iPod.volume>.1){
        iPod.volume -= .1;
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
});
```

Comment: Dude, can we mix two songs? Like fading out current item and fading in next item?

Comment: please see my comment above. I am in big trouble out here. Ay help is appreciated.