# Hide Volume Level Pop Up MPMusicPlayerController Xcode

Tags: xcode, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using MPMusicPlayerController to play a list of mp3 in my app.

The only problem is when I set the volume level, according with app configuration, appears a Volume Level pop up.

I tried to find any property in order to hide it, but I didn't find.

The code I'm using is:

```
if (audioPlayer)
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
        [audioPlayer stop];

self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.musicPlayer];

[self.musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];

[self.musicPlayer setAccessibilityElementsHidden:YES];
self.musicPlayer.volume = volume;

[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];

self.musicPlayer.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatModeAll;

[self.musicPlayer play];
```

My question is, Any way to avoid this pop up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem in other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797726/fade-out-playback-volume-on-mpmusicplayercontroller-on-ios-5)

But, there is not a direct way to perform that without using MPVolumeView "invisible"?

Sorry :)